# Crossed boolean as mutex

Tags: concurrency, boolean, mutex

quick question:

foo1 and foo2 use (read and modify) the same shared boo object from different threads, so they should be mutex'ed.

I'm not sure if I can use crossed booleans instead of a mutex in this case of concurrency.

Thread 1:

```
void foo1()
{
    if(mutex == true)
    {
        boo.modifyThis();
        mutex = false;
    }
}
```

Thread 2:

```
void foo2()
{
    if(mutex == false)
    {
        boo.modifyThat();
        mutex = true;
    }
}
```

What do you think? Do you see any flaws?

Thank you!

Edit: modifyThis and modifyThat only change internal members of boo. There are only 2 threads, and they only call their corresponding foo# function.

Comment: What you expect from your `foo1()` and `foo2()` functions? It is impossible to say anithing about correctness without that information.

Comment: edited for comprehension, hope its enough!

Comment: Assuming, e.g., `mutex` variable initially is false, `foo1()` will do nothing until `foo2()` is called before. Similary, calling `foo2()` again will do nothing until `foo1()` is called between. If it is OK for you, you code is correct if mutex is declated as `atomic<bool> mutex`.

Comment: @MartinMatilla, In this case, there can potentially be multiple threads calling `boo.modifyThat()` or `boo.modifyThis()` which may or may not be safe (depending on if the intended use for this is SPSC). Another thing that may crop up is that the store to the `mutex` might be reordered with the function call, effectively eliminating the exclusion if `mutex` isn't atomic.

Comment: Edited the question again! Anyway, thank you for your comments, they are are both right.
I only intend to call each foo# function from each thread#, and its ok that foo2 doesn't access boo before foo1 etc..
@Alejandro please elaborate the "store to the mutex might be reordered", I dont understand what you mean, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the threads belong to the same process, you should setup a critical section (the `lock` keyword in *C#*) to protect `boo.modifyThat()` from being called concurrently.

### DESIGN ISSUE

If you are using a mutex or critical section to prevent multiple threads from executing code concurrently, I would recommend that you **avoid calling methods from within a protected block of code**.

It is possible that `boo.modifyThat()` could try to enter another critical section.  Depending on how the source code has been written, you may find that you have inadvertently created a deadlock.  This becomes an even bigger problem when more and more developers start working on the same code base.

In otherwords, calling methods from within a critical section increases the *risk* that a threading issue *may be* introduced in the future.

## ADDITIONAL READING

The original post makes no mention of the programming language being used.  Regardless, the same rule applies.

If you are programming in C# .NET, take a look at the following:

- [MSDN: lock keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)
- [Wikipedia: Deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)